# initiate rfq failed: noTradersAvailable_tse

Tags: java, fix-protocol, quickfixj

When I send `quickfix.fix44.QuoteRequest()` to `CurreneX` I get error:

```
58=initiate rfq failed: noTradersAvailable_tse
```

I can not faund what it means

Comment: This isn't part of the FIX protocol; it has been put into the text field by CurreneX. The reason that you didn't get a quote back (from the text) is that there weren't any traders available to give you a quote. Did you request the quote on something that was actively trading at the time?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a FIX or QuickFIX problem.  This is an error message from CurreneX.

You will need to contact CurreneX or check their documentation.